# ffmpeg - output silent audio track if source has no audio or audio is shorter than source video

Tags: ffmpeg

I need a video file whose audio and video track duration are always the same.  The file must contain an audio track even if source audio has no audio track.  How do I tell ffmpeg to add a silent audio track when source has no audio trace.  Also, if source has an audio track that is a different duration than the video, I need ffmpeg to append silent audio to make both output audio and video the same duration.  Is this possible in one line with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 10):

The command below will add a silent track of the same length* as the video, if there is no audio** in the source file.

```
ffmpeg -i video -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=1 -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mov
```

*Since video frame duration and audio frame duration aren't usually identical, the lengths won't be exactly the same.

**when `map` is not specified, ffmpeg selects a single audio stream from among the inputs with the highest channel count. If there are two or more streams with same no. of channels, it selects stream with lowest index. `anullsrc` here has one channel, so it will be passed over except when source has no audio.

Comment: Ok, but I need to pass the source audio if it exists add silent track if it doesn't.

Comment: Can you explain -f lavfi?  I need to output h264 in .mov container regardless of input format.

Comment: That tells FFmpeg that the next input `anullsrc` is a filter generator. Edited cmd for H264 output.